# Store HTML table data in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to store my html table data in an array using jQuery. One of the fields contains a dropdown list. The below code works fine but dropdown list data is not fetched.
Can someone help?

```
var myTableArray = [];

$("table#tblClassificationSearchResult tr").each(function () {
    var arrayOfThisRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
        tableData.each(function () { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
        myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not 100% sure, but I think this should work:

```
var myTableArray = [];

$("table#tblClassificationSearchResult tr").each(function() {
  var arrayOfThisRow = [];
  var tableData = $(this).find('td');
  if (tableData.length > 0) {
    tableData.each(function() {
      if ($(this).find('input').prop('type') == 'select') {
        arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).find('input').val());
      } else {
        arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text());
      }
    });
    myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the id of the dropdown stored in array and store the dropdown options separately in an array with index.
if you just wantto store content of each td then best is to serialise it and store it and then deserialise and restore it when needed.